# Can anyone recommend any good Domain Modelling/Taxonomy tools?

Tags: ux-field, tools

I work as part of an agile team with distinct disciplines - at the moment we use Confluence as our wiki space for projects - and therefore it's the most sensible place for our living, breathing domain model and taxonomy. I'm interested to know if there are any other more appropriate tools out there that people can recommend - or that have more value than a mere sketch.